# How to show a WPF window above a TaskBar icon?

Tags: wpf

In Google's Chrome App Launcher for Windows, does anyone know how they managed to show the window such that it's centered above the application's icon in the TaskBar? Any kind of solution for C#/.NET would be fine (p/invoke, etc.).

I've searched high and low and there are solutions for the System Tray based on identifying the screen rect of a notify icon, but I have not found one for the TaskBar (except one approach that is based on a screen capture, but it's too fragile for production applications).

Thanks!

-Tom B.

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: Seems like there could be a lot of way this could be done.  Could be a transparent window with vertical alignment of the content set to bottom and a setting a calculated Window.Left.  It could be using pinvoke to pull theme info, icon style, dimensions, etc, and just use a no border style window, where unfocus = closing app.  Its up to you.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I wasn't more specific, but yeah, what I can't figure out is how to calculate the position of the left side of the window. Everything else is pretty straightforward.

Comment: If you're following the vertical alignment approach, you could use your mouse coordinates to get its X position and set the Window.Left = mousePositionX - (.5 * Window.Width).

Comment: What he means is that he doesn't know how to figure out the screen bounds for the taskbar icon.  He wants to use that as an anchor.  I think [this article](http://blog.strixcode.com/2011/01/how-to-find-taskbar-button-position-on.html) may be just what you need.

Comment: So I think NETscape is on the right trail with the mouse position. If you launch the app from the desktop icon, or if you click on the icon in the TaskBar and then immediately move the mouse to the top of the screen, then the window appears anchored to the lower-left corner of the screen. So it looks like the app checks the position of the mouse on startup, and if it is within the TaskBar bounds, then it shows the window above the mouse. Tricky!

Comment: Thanks Mike, but the approach in that article relies on screen captures and the visual appearance of the TaskBar, which might change, so I didn't want to go that route.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to NETscape's hint, I found that the way that the Chrome App Launcher makes it look like the window is appearing over the TaskBar icon is by checking the mouse position immediately after starting up, and if the mouse is in the TaskBar area then it shows the window directly above the TaskBar and horizontally centered over the mouse.

You can test this by moving the mouse left or right immediately after clicking the icon, in which cases the window appears to the left or right of the TaskBar icon. If you move the mouse outside the TaskBar area right after clicking it (or launch the app from a Desktop icon) then the window is just anchored to the lower-left corner of the screen.